Remove string from column across group of rows in another column
I would like to remove a string from one column across a group of rows in another column. In the below reprex, I would like to remove the string in snippet from the string in text in any row in the group id. So, for id == "p1", both "apple" and "orange" should be removed from both rows of text for that group, leaving " and "; "apple" should not be removed for other groups, e.g., for id == "p2", text should remain "fruits with apple".
I tried to use dplyr::group_by and stringr::str_remove_all, which didn't work.
Thank you for your help.
library(dplyr)

df_in <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~snippet, ~text,
  "p1", "apple", " and orange",
  "p1", "orange", "apple and ",
  "p2", "kiwi", "fruits with apple"
)

df_out <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~snippet, ~text,
  "p1", "apple", " and ",
  "p1", "orange", " and ",
  "p2", "kiwi", "fruits with apple"
)

# DOESN'T WORK
df_in |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(text = stringr::str_remove_all(text, snippet))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    snippet text               
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>              
#> 1 p1    apple   " and orange"      
#> 2 p1    orange  "apple and "       
#> 3 p2    kiwi    "fruits with apple"

Created on 2024-07-16 with reprex v2.0.2

My first idea was f=\(text, snippet) {x=unlist(strsplit(text, " ")); paste(x[!x %in% snippet], collapse=" ")}; lapply(split(df_in, ~id), \(x) {y = x$snippet; lapply(x$text, \(i) f(i, y))}). I think it works (haven't tested), but I do not like it. Based on this logic one might develope a less computationally intensive approach.

The trick is that you need to add a | in the regex. So you just need to modify the code like this
library(tidyverse)


df_in <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~snippet, ~text,
  "p1", "apple", " and orange",
  "p1", "orange", "apple and ",
  "p2", "kiwi", "fruits with apple"
)


df_in |>
  mutate(text = str_remove_all(text,
                              paste(snippet, collapse = '|')), .by = id)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   id    snippet text               
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>              
#> 1 p1    apple   " and "            
#> 2 p1    orange  " and "            
#> 3 p2    kiwi    "fruits with apple"

Created on 2024-07-16 with reprex v2.1.1

Here's a purrr alternative:
# Pkgs (purrr, dplyr) -----------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~snippet, ~text,
  "p1", "apple", " and orange",
  "p1", "orange", "apple and ",
  "p2", "kiwi", "fruits with apple")

# Code --------------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = id, 
    new_text = reduce(snippet, \(x, y) str_remove_all(x, y), .init = text))

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
my_df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   id    snippet text                new_text           
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>               <chr>              
#> 1 p1    apple   " and orange"       " and "            
#> 2 p1    orange  "apple and "        " and "            
#> 3 p2    kiwi    "fruits with apple" "fruits with apple"

Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.1.0
